# Using statement return reference type

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, using, datacontext, eager-loading

I'm using Linq to SQL and for optimization I want to set DataContext.ObjectTrackingEnabled to false for queries where I don't need to change or add objects. In my application I have a DataContext that's used all over, so in order for me to set ObjectTrackingEnabled to false I need to create a new DataContext. So I want to do something like this:

```
    public static MyObj GetMyObj(long id)
    {
        using (MyDataContext dc = new MyDataDataContext("connectionstring"))
        {
            dc.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
            return dc.MyObjs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
        }
    }
```

But it seems the MyObj that I'm returning gets "half disposed" because when I try to access it's members they all turn out to be null. Like so:

```
    var myObj = GetMyObj(10);
    var test = myObj.MyMember.Count(); // MyMember is now null, but shouldn't be
```

However, if I don't do the using, then I get the correct Count():

```
    public static MyObj GetMyObj(long id)
    {
        var dc = DCManager.Get("myDataContext") // gets the normal DC that's used throughout the application
        return dc.MyObjs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
    }

    var myObj = GetMyObj(10);
    var test = myObj.MyMember.Count(); // MyMember is now not null and its Count() is not 0
```

Is there a way that I can use ObjectTrackingEnabled = false without losing data on my return value or can I only use this "pattern" when returning value types? I guess I need to force eager loading on the member objects I want to use after the return, so I tried adding DataLoadOptions.LoadWith but I'm still not getting the underlying objects:

```
    public static MyObj GetMyObj(long id)
    {
        using (MyDataContext dc = new MyDataDataContext("connectionstring"))
        {
            dc.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
            DataLoadOptions load = new DataLoadOptions();
            load.LoadWith<MyObj>(d => d.MyMember);
            return dc.MyObjs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
        }
    }

    var myObj = GetMyObj(10);
    var test = myObj.MyMember.Count(); // MyMember is null which it shouldn't be
```

Comment: Use obj as the return type instead of MyObj.

Comment: Do you mean "public static object GetMyObj(long id)"?

Comment: Yes.  I forgot to put the link : https://github.com/sankarr/Nmodbus/blob/master/Modbus/Device/ModbusIpMaster.cs and line : private static byte ModbusId;

Comment: Having the method return an object instead of a MyObj and didn't change anything, and I don't see what that code has to do with solving my problem. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: You are returning FirstOrDefault() and then trying to get the 10th item when you only returned one item.

Comment: Ah, no. I'm trying to fetch item with ID 10 and the IDs are unique so there is only one such item. Thank you though.

Comment: Are you getting an exception?  Replace the using statement with a try/catch.  The using is probably not reporting the exception.

Comment: No, I'm not getting an exception (unless I try to do something with the object that's null because of the lazy loading). I think I'm on the right track with Damien's answer below, so I'm trying that for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got very close with your latest updates. You're right that this is about lazy/eager loading. But you've failed to tell *that specific context object* to [use the options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext.loadoptions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_Linq_DataContext_LoadOptions) you've configured:

```
public static MyObj GetMyObj(long id)
{
    using (MyDataContext dc = new MyDataDataContext("connectionstring"))
    {
        dc.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
        DataLoadOptions load = new DataLoadOptions();
        load.LoadWith<MyObj>(d => d.MyMember);

        dc.LoadOptions = load; //<-- New line

        return dc.MyObjs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
    }
}

var myObj = GetMyObj(10);
var test = myObj.MyMember.Count(); // MyMember is null which it shouldn't be
```

(As a preference, I'd also rename `load` as `options` because I think that better describes what that object is)